# What is the theoretical average latency of data transmission?

Tags: blockchain, infura, timestamp, block-interval, block-header

I concluded a pretty simple test to measure some latencies. I connected to two providers (Infura and Quiknode) with Web3.js and subscribed to new block headers. Then I compared the time of arrival and the block timestamp in the header to calculate a latency. I got the following results (left Infura, right Quiknode):[image]

Both of them has a pretty high latency. Is this due to their complex infrastructure, or due to the P2P nature of the blockchain? This seems too high for me, so I guess I can achieve much lower latencies by running my own node. Is this likey?

What is theoretical average latency of such a distributed network?

Comment: typical latency on internet is 100 ms: https://wondernetwork.com/pings/New%20York

Comment: Yes, it's clear, but not every node is connected to every nodes that's why the information propagation through a p2p network takes a lot of steps until arrives to me.